# How to fix a setter that is throwing undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a geolocation class so that I can call that class when and where I need it but I ran into a problem, and keep getting the error.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLatitude' of undefined
    at setCurrentPosition (geolocation.js:13)`

Any guidance would be apprecitated?

```
 class Geolocation {
    constructor() {
        this.latitude = 0;
        this.longitude = 0;
    }

    getGeoLocation() {
        if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setCurrentPosition);
        }
    }
    setCurrentPosition(position) {
        this.setLatitude(position.coords.latitude);
        this.setLongitude(position.coords.longitude);
    }
    setLatitude(latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    setLongitude(longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    getLatitude() {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind to the correct `this`:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setCurrentPosition.bind(this))
```

Comment: I did not know about bind. Thank you! I am trying to stay in the best practice and use separation of concerns pratice.  Is this the best way to write this code?

Comment: You are doing it correctly but if you need a function which has a callback, then you need to use the correct `this` as context because the callback function has its own context, which is different. So yes I'd say this is pretty much how you'd do it

Answer (score 0):

The `this` is not pointing to the class instance of `Geolocation`. You need to bind the `this` to the instance in the `constructor`:

```
constructor() {
   this.latitude = 0;
   this.longitude = 0;
   this.setCurrentPosition = this.setCurrentPosition.bind(this);
}
```